# Laplacian Filter Implementation in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab, filters, filtering

I implemented a Laplacian filter for the Lena image, but I get an unexpected output.

For input:

[image: lena image with 3x3 mean filter]

I get output:

[image: my Laplacian filter implementation]

I used the mask

```
M =

     0    -1     0
    -1     5    -1
     0    -1     0
```

`I` is my [Lenna Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) rows and columns are `I.rows` and `I.columns`.

And this is my MATLAB function:

```
function IM = customMaskImage(I, rows, columns, M)
IM = zeros(rows,columns);
[mask_rows, mask_columns] = size(M);

for i = 1+(mask_rows-1)/2:(rows - (mask_rows-1)/2)
    for j = 1+(mask_columns-1)/2:(columns - (mask_columns-1)/2)
        tmpMat = I(i-(mask_rows-1)/2:i+(mask_rows-1)/2,j-(mask_columns-1)/2:j+(mask_columns-1)/2);
        IM(i,j) = sum(sum(customMatConv(tmpMat, 3, 3, M)));
    end
end

end
```

`customMatConv.m` is:

```
function IM = customMatConv(I, rows, columns, M)
IM = zeros(rows,columns);

for i = 1:rows
    for j = 1:columns
        IM(i,j) = I(i,j) * M(i,j);
    end
end

end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the function customMatConv do ?

Comment: Sorry for that customMatConv does same as A.*B which means  customMatConv(A,B, A.rows, A.columns) = A.*B

Answer (score 2):

The first wrong doing is the $5$in the middle of the kernel:

```
 0    -1     0
-1     5    -1
 0    -1     0
```

A second derivative "cannot" have its coefficients sum to a non-zero value. The two standard $3\times 3$ Laplacians are:

```
 0    -1     0
-1     4    -1
 0    -1     0
```

and

```
 -1    -1     -1
 -1     8    -1
 -1    -1     -1
```

The second issue could be a format one: is your input cast to single or double float, as integer operations may be troublesome?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `conv2()` or `imfilter()` with your filter.
Unless you want to implement it by hand,

Comment: It is my homework so, I should not use Matlab functions without undestanding it's inner workings.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following Laplace mask
0   1   0
1   -4  1
0   1   0

on the highlighted pixel below and find its intensity value in the corresponding filtered image.

50  60  70      65  80
40  100     120     80  70
150 110     100     96  85
30  105     75      50  40
65  125 35      80  90